# how to revert single edited row in dojo dgrid?

Tags: javascript, dojo, grid, dgrid

Is there a way to revert/reset the edited row in the dojo-dgrid ?

I can see the grid.revert() which does clear the dirty items and calls the refresh method, which will refresh the whole grid. I don't want this whole grid-refresh.

Is it possible to reset/revert only that single edited row, upon clicking a Revert/Cancel Icon on the Actions-column (which will be the last column in the grid as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13027345/dojo-dgrid-multiple-cells-edit) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176157/dojo-editable-tree-dgrid-create-or-generate-a-new-row-like-store-newitem-sup))

Answer (score 2):

If you're wrapping your store with [*Observable*](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/Observable.html), you can use *notify()* to update a single row.

For example, you can create the following code for *onClick* event of your Revert/Cancel button:

```dojo
 renderCell: function(object, data, cell){

   var btnRevert = new Button({
     label: "Revert",
     // ...
     onClick: function(evt){
       var dirty = that.grid.dirty,
           id = object.id;

       if(dirty.hasOwnProperty(id)){
         // remove dirty data
         delete dirty[id];
         // ..and notify the store to update
         myStore.notify(object, object.id);
       }
     }
   }, cell.appendChild(put("div")) );

   return btnRevert;
 }
```

Here is a jsfiddle with an example: [revert example](http://jsfiddle.net/knokit/KFkNB/4/)